# How to add param to single action route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested route denoting a single action, which works as expected in the following way:

```rb
resources :abilities, param: :slug do
  delete '/company/:slug', controller: :ability_companies, action: :destroy
end
```

However, all my routes are defined as symbols, with the param name defined as an attribute, and I'd like to keep my route definitions coherent.

The following syntax seems to follow the logic I use elsewhere, but it doesn't work and I cannot figure out why.

```rb
delete :company, controller: :ability_companies, action: :destroy, param: :slug
```

With the above line, I get a 404 error. What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Have you checked the result of `rails routes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up treating the nested route as a nested resource. The result is more semantic (plural "companies") and cleaner as well, given how 90% of my routes are handled on a resource-level.

The resulting lines of code:

```rb
resources :abilities, param: :slug do
  resources :companies, controller: :ability_companies, param: :company_slug, only: [:destroy, :create]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

on config/routes.rb

```
resources :abilities, only: [ :destroy ], as: :destroy
```

---

on app/controllers/ability_contoller.rb

```
  def destroy
    @ability = Ability.find(params[:my_params])
    @ability.destroy
    redirect_to any_path
  end

  private
  def my_params
    params.require(:abilities).permit(:slug )
  end
```